# Prepared statement help, Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm getting this error : Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
every time I run this code:

```
$dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "pics");
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (username, picture, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_Param('s', $username);
   $stmt->bind_Param('d', $picture);
   $stmt->bind_Param('s', $comment);

   $username=$_SESSION['username'];
   $picture=$_GET['id'];
   $comment=$_POST['comment'];
   $stmt->execute();
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting all the parameters into one `bindParam` call:

```
$stmt->bind_Param('sds', $username, $picture, $comment);
```

Comment: Let me suggest to remove an addendum to your post

Comment: what's unclear? it does work and it's the answer. while added section has no relation to the question. yes, he need to check types, but that's not a cause.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Removed, just to make you happy! I just got a little confused by your syntax :-)

Comment: Sorry i mean the bind_Param() with the capital letter P , is there any different or just a typing error?

Comment: @LeonArmstrong Class methods are not case sensitive (neither are functions, or keywords, whereas properties, variables and constants are: this is one of PHP's charming eccentricities/idiotic design decisions).

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks for the explanation and sharing , i was too into java , never figure out php are actually work this way =)